# React refs created from Array not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use `ref`s created from an array but when I check in the Component tab of the React Developper Tools, `ref` passed to the `input` are always `undefined`. Something I missed here?

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const refs = useMemo(() => Array(2).fill(0).map(i => React.createRef()), []);

  const TextInput = ({ name, value, inputRef }) => (
    <input
      name={name}
      value={value}
      onChange={updateField()}
      ref={inputRef}
    />
  )

  return (
    <TextInput
      name="lastname"
      value="Nom *"
      inputRef={refs[0]}
    />
    <TextInput
      name="firstname"
      label="Prénom *"
      inputRef={refs[1]}
    />
  )
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `i` in `refs[i]`?

Comment: Sorry @JayendraSharan , I don't use `i` anymore. I updated my sample code.

Comment: What are you attempting to do here? Why not just use two `useRef`s?

Comment: @AKX I could if I always had a fixed number of `TextInput` components. But it can occur that the number of components vary and I have to generate `ref`s dynamically in that case.

Comment: That will be easiest done with a function-style ref instead.

Comment: @AKX How would you do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a variable number of refs, you'll want a function-style ref instead, like below.

```
const TextInput = ({
  name,
  value,
  refs
}) => (
  <input
    name={name}
    value={value}
    ref={(el) => {
      refs.current[name] = el;
    }}
  />
);

const MyComponent = () => {
  const refs = React.useRef({});

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log(refs.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput name="lastname" value="Nom *" refs={refs} />
      <TextInput name="firstname" value="Prénom *" refs={refs} />
    </>
  );
};
```

This will log

```
{lastname: HTMLInputElement, firstname: HTMLInputElement}
```

As an aside: never nest components – that will cause unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: It doesn't work as I'd like. First, I don't see both refs logged, just the initial value `{}`. And in my actual code, I try to `focus()` on `refs.current[name]`, but only one `input` can be edited at one point(because of unique `ref` in the `refs` obj). I would like to focus on both input at the same time. I guess it would work if I'd had the two `ref` originally created as shown in your "log".

Comment: Only one element can have focus at any given time. You can't have two simultaneously `focus()`ed elements.

Comment: You're right, sorry for my confused comment. It's just that when the first input has focus, I have to click twice on the second one to set focus on it.

Comment: The focus problem was not related to your pattern. It works now. Thanks, I did know I could pass a callback as `ref`.